How may I share the same message format for MessageFormat.format and sfl4j logger without invoking MessageFormat.format inside sfl4j logger methods?
I have a property file where I put my error messages. They are used for logging, but not only.
The trouble I have, is that MessageFormat.format(...) and slf4j info, warn, error(...) methods don't share the same message format.
One uses: {0}, {1}... the other {}, {}...
In my property file, I would like to have only one version of a given message:
Either MESSAGE_A or MESSAGE_B (below), but only one of them.
MESSAGE_A=Un numéro de compte {} a une nomenclature invalide: {}
MESSAGE_B=Un numéro de compte {0} a une nomenclature invalide: {1}

Currently, if I create String MESSAGE_A, MESSAGE_B... from the properties above and use them in the next Java sample, I will have for result what is in comment:
Logger LOGGER = LoggerFactory.getLogger(...)
LOGGER.warn(MESSAGE_A, "215756", "M85"); // Un numéro de compte 215756 a une nomenclature invalide: M85
LOGGER.warn(MESSAGE_B, "215756", "M85"); // Un numéro de compte {0} a une nomenclature invalide: {1}

MessageFormat.format(MESSAGE_A, "215756", "M85"); // Error or wrongly formatted message
MessageFormat.format(MESSAGE_B, "215756", "M85"); // Un numéro de compte 215756 a une nomenclature invalide: M85

The workaround I have is to apply MessageFormat.format() inside the LOGGER method called:
LOGGER.warn(MessageFormat.format(MESSAGE_B, "215756", "M85"))

But it's clumsy. Is there a better way to manage this problem?

You can write a helper method which converts the format string for one "engine" to the format of the other "engine". In this case you could write a converter which converts from java.text.MessageFormat format to SLF4J format by replacing every {N} with {}. The method could look like this:
public static String toSLF4JFormat(String messageFormat) {
    String regex = "\\{\\d+\\}";
    String replacement = "{}";
    String result = messageFormat.replaceAll(regex, replacement);
    return result;
}

Then you can use this helper method at your LOGGER calls:
LOGGER.warn(FormatHelper.toSLF4JFormat(MESSAGE_B), "215756", "M85");

That way you only need one format string (the one in MessageFormat format).
You obviously loose the ability to rearrange the order of arguments in MessageFormat or you must take care of the order of the arguments. When you have a (MessageFormat) logging string like:
The system {1} does not support the type {2} while running in {0} mode.

it will become
The system {} does not support the type {} while running in {} mode.

and the position for the arguments aren't (1,2,0) anymore but the normal order (0,1,2). To make this work you have to rearrange the arguments for the LOGGER.warn() calls as well:
MessageFormat.format(MESSAGE_FOOBAR, "DEBUG", "ACME", "int32");
LOGGER.warn(FormatHelper.toSLF4JFormat(MESSAGE_FOOBAR), "ACME", "int32", "DEBUG");

